# Enumerating files in rapidly changing directory

Tags: c#, filesystems, filesystemwatcher, enumerator

I have a folder with lot of files in it (let's say 100,000 files).
Another process is rapidly creating new files into that folder and I want to efficiently track these newly created files(`FileSystemWatcher` can't help here since I get lots of 'Too many changes at once' exceptions).

So I thought I can tackle this by using Directory.EnumerateFiles(...), simply keep the enumerator and performing 'MoveNext()' a couple of times per second, that way I don't need to go over all the files that were already created each time.

Problem is that it seems as if the enumerator is working on a cached-version of the directory, which means I never get the newly created files (unless resetting the enumerator, which means going over the entire content of the directory again).

I also tried the [FastDirectoryEnumerator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38959/A-Faster-Directory-Enumerator?msg=4601924#xx4601924xx) from CodeProject (though deep down I knew they are probably working exactly the same) but got the same result.

I really hope there's another elegant way to workaround this, any idea?

Comment: Could you maybe post some code here so we have something to work with?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new Enumerable and using the Skip() method with a counter that you maintain?  It's not elegant, but I suspect FileSystemWatcher may be doing something similar.

Comment: @Rob Using skip won't help since it's efficiency is O(n), which basically means that it simply performing MoveNext() operation n times.

Comment: Yes, there's always a way - use a filter driver to track file creations on the fly. And forget about FileSystemWatcher.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Is it possible to do so in c#? can you please give more information on the subject?

Comment: @Nissim I had a feeling that might be the case.  Looking around the web, it seems that your choices aren't that palatable.  You can try tweaking InternalBufferSize and NotifyFilter in the hope that you can beat FileSystemWatcher into submission, but that's not recommended.  The filter driver option works if you're happy to take responsibility for any unintended consequences.  Let us know how you get on, though.

Comment: @Nissim Our CallbackFilter ( http://www.eldos.com/cbflt ) is a possible option.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Will it also work on network drives?

Comment: @Nissim if those drives are updated locally. If files are added on the server and you must grab them on the client, then unfortunately you are completely out of luck and need to review your application design.